# List of random existing IP addresses

Tags: routing, internet

I would need a list of IP addresses (that can be reached by traceroute), preferably in random physical locations.

Is it possible to generate such a list from RIPE, ARIN and APNIC? If so, how would I do that? Or is there some other tool for generating random reachable IP addresses?

The list should contain at least 100 IP addresses.

Comment: How random does this have to be and why do you need this?  Does this have to be calculated offline or can it be generated online?  Is there a problem with picking a list of random internet prefixes, and picking only one active IP from each prefix?  Technically that isn't truly random but it's the simplest solution within the constraints

Comment: I'm doing a small project in a networking course, and my objective is to build a BASH script to calculate the average number of hops to reach hosts in different regions. I just need a list of IP addresses that can be reached with traceroute in a file basically. In a perfect world they'd be divided into Europe, America and Asia and randomly distributed within these regions... Right now I'm just generating random IP's and doing traceroute for them, which is very time consuming since only 5% - 10% of them are reachable withing 30 hops, not to mention that I can't be sure where they're located...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A crude, but functional way of finding addresses within the scope of what you’re looking for is pretty simple, given you find the right site.  Personally, I’d just crawl through [NirSoft’s Major IP Address Blocks By Country](http://www.nirsoft.net/countryip/).  Not entirely sure how reliable or up to date this site is, but it's the best I found.

If you do a `curl` on that link combined with a couple parsing parameters, you’d come up with something like this.

```
Ryans-MacBook-Pro-4:~ ryan$ curl -s http://www.nirsoft.net/countryip/ | grep "<td><a"
<td><a href="af.html">Afghanistan</a>
<td><a href="al.html">Albania</a>
<td><a href="dz.html">Algeria</a>
<td><a href="as.html">American Samoa</a>
<td><a href="ad.html">Andorra</a>
<...snip...>
<td><a href="ye.html">Yemen</a>
<td><a href="zm.html">Zambia</a>
<td><a href="zw.html">Zimbabwe</a>
```

From there, you just iterate through each `href` and replace the .html with .csv to get an usable output.  For example, if you wanted to see what IP spaces Yemen was using, I used:

```
Ryans-MacBook-Pro-4:~ ryan$ curl -s http://www.nirsoft.net/countryip/ye.csv
31.31.176.0,31.31.191.255,4096,21/03/11,Public Telecommunication Corporation
46.35.64.0,46.35.95.255,8192,13/10/10,Public Telecommunication Corporation
78.137.64.0,78.137.95.255,8192,11/09/12,Public Telecommunication Corporation
82.114.160.0,82.114.191.255,8192,30/12/03,Public Telecommunication Corporation
89.189.64.0,89.189.95.255,8192,11/10/06,Public Telecommunication Corporation
109.74.32.0,109.74.47.255,4096,20/10/09,Public Telecommunication Corporation
109.200.160.0,109.200.191.255,8192,05/02/10,Public Telecommunication Corporation
195.94.0.0,195.94.31.255,8192,15/08/96,TeleYemen
```

Some basic syntax would make it usable; like taking the first subnet in each section.

```
Ryans-MacBook-Pro-4:~ ryan$ curl -s http://www.nirsoft.net/countryip/ye.csv | head -1 \
 | cut -d "," -f 1-2 | tr "," " "
31.31.176.0 31.31.191.255
```

For obvious reasons we aren’t going to automate this entire process for you, but this should set you off in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

[NLNOG Ring](http://ring.nlnog.net) nodes could be useful for this. https://ring.nlnog.net/api/1.0/nodes has a nice parseable list of nodes, http://map.ring.nlnog.net shows them on a map.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Hurricane Electric internet services website, http://lg.he.net/ . They have a list of looking glasses from Europe, North America and Asia with the listed cities of their location. place your pointer on any of them, write down the address (this you will have to do manually) and trace it. Pick IP address being traced Looking glassess always have traceroute enabled

Answer (score 1):

Reach out to the authors of masscan for the list of live IP addresses they found. You should then be able to feed them into a structure from which you can pull out elements at random.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer by Ryan Foley looks nice!

However, I ended up going for a totally different tactic. Using a BASH script, I simply generated IP's with four random numbers 0-255. I then ran traceroute on them via another BASH script with a success rate of 5% - 10% within 30 hops. Then I ran the IP's that gave a successful traceroute result through yet another BASH script, using https://freegeoip.net to get the country of the IP address and then manually assigning that to a region.

One could also use the list at http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv4-address-space/ipv4-address-space.xhtml to get the region (Africa, North America, South America, Europe, Asia) of the IP.

If I would do this again I would've tried the accepted solution, mainly because running traceroute on 2500 IP's and only getting 200 successful results was quite time consuming.